# How to structure an app that is used for multiple clients, but has slight variations for each?

Tags: php, laravel

So here's the deal.

We're building an app for multiple clients on the same server. It's basically the same app, but for every client we have slight variations in routes and console commands, different implementations for a few interfaces, including unit tests for those implementations, different blade views for our emails and finally we have slightly different frontend javascript per client as well.

We're struggling a bit on how to structure this properly.

Right now we have this folder structure:

- /app (this is the main app)
- /tests (all the tests of the main app's implementations)
- /clients

  - /first-client.com

    - /app
    - /tests
    - /resources
  - /second-client.com

    - /app
    - /tests
    - /resources
- /public

  - /first-client.com/
  - /second-client.com/

All client-specific classes live in their own namespace, `FirstClient` and `SecondClient` respectively. We're using Laravel 5.1, so the routes files are in /clients/first-client.com/app/Http/routes.php etc.

We're keeping the public folders outside of the `/clients` folder, because the frontend is a completely separate big angular repository.

Now here's a few issues we're dealing with:

1. Right now we're bootstrapping the app in a bit of an ugly way. In `/public/first-client.com/index.php` we define a constant to save which client we started in. Then in `/bootstrap/app.php` we use a singleton class (which uses the constant defined earlier) to find the correct client-specific Kernel classes. All that usage of global constants and global singletons is freaking me out.
2. When a client-specific test wants to simulate an HTTP request, how can we make sure it runs it using the correct client environment and routes etc?

You don't have to answer these questions per se. I can imagine that more people have tried to do something like this and maybe you found a completely different and much better way of structuring this. If that's the case then I'd love to hear how you did it.